# Width and Height of GetFeatureInfoUrl request with Openlayers 4.x and Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, html, getfeatureinfo

When I make a getGetFeatureInfoUrl request with OpenLayers 4.x, Geoserver 2.10.1 and WMS 1.3.0 with the code below, the width and height returned default to 256.

```
var url = lyr.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
evt.coordinate, viewResolution, viewProjection,
{'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html', 'FEATURE_COUNT': 50, 'WIDTH': 500, 
'HEIGHT':500});
```

If I set the popup I display it in to dynamically resize, it too is always 256x256, leaving empty space if there are only a few fields or long scroll bars if there is a lot of data.

Am I setting the params wrong?  Do I have to change the html formatting with a .flt file in the Geoserver templates directory?  Ideally, I'd like to know the actual width and height or not pass them at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Width and Height in a GetFeatureInfo request relate to the width and height of the Map (product of a GetMap request) to which you are supplying your I/J pixel coordinate.  This has nothing to do with the size of the response.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is any way to work out the size of the html returned from a getfeatureinfo request before it returned.

If the sizing and presentation of the information is important to you then request the information in a machine readable format like json or gml and produce exactly the display you want.